# Can a Jew use someone else’s Chumash for Shnayim mikra

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, pentateuch-chumash, shnayim-mikra, orach-chaim

According to Halacha, is it permissible for a Jew to fulfill the mitzvah of Shnayim Mikra V’echad Targum by using someone else’s Chumash (with their consent of course)? Or does one have to own the Chumash to fulfill it?

Is it similar to Lulav on Sukkot where the law is that it has to belong to you to be Chiyuv in the mitzvah?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all from the fact this halacha is sourced in the gemara ([Berachot 8a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.8a.30?lang=bi)), one sees there is no need to own a Chumash, since certainly in those times there was no personal Chumash to be had.

R Avihud Schwartz notes ([here](https://etzion.org.il/en/tanakh/torah/sefer-bereishit/shenayim-mikra-ve-echad-targum), 3a) that R Ovadia Yosef wrote

> One who has a sefer Torah in his possession and who knows the
> cantillation and vowels by heart should ideally read shenayim mikra
> ve-echad targum from the sefer Torah, for it is very holy.
>
> In the footnote there, R. Yosef mentions that this was indeed the
> practice  of the Ari. He would go to the synagogue or study hall, take
> the sefer Torah out of the aron, and read the weekly parasha from it.

Clearly the reference is to one who has access to a sefer Torah, not just one who owns his personal sefer Torah as very few people do.